# How to UPDATE on Child, the reference of Parent upon Parent deletion?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm making this question since I'm having a hard time asking the right question when I research. I hope to be clear:

I've got 2 Schemas:

**Parent [TEAM]:**

```
const EquipaSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    trab1: { 
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'Trab'
    },
    trab2: { 
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'Trab'
    },
    trab3: { 
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'Trab'
    },
    teamName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    marcsEquipa: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Marcacao'
    }]
},
{collection: 'Equipas'})
```

**And Child [Project]:**

```
const MarcacaoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    name: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true },
    date: { type: Date, required: true},
    hour: { type: String, required: true},
    type: { type: String, required: true},
    address: {type: String, required: true},
    state: {type: String, default: 'Pendente'},
    // equipa: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Equipa' },
    equipa: {
        type: String,
        default: 'Não'
    },
    cliente: { 
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'User'
    },
    aval_admin: {
        type: String,
        default: "Sem Avaliação pelo Manager"
    },
    descricao: {
        type: String,
        default: "Sem Descrição"
    },
    aval_client: {
        type: String,
        default: "Sem Avaliação do Cliente"
    },
    avaliado: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    team: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Equipas'
    }

},
{collection: 'Marcacao'}
```

**My goal is**:  When a team is deleted, all of the projects in the team array ['marcsEquipa[]'] get updated to {team: null}, so that I can assign a NEW team to the SAME project.

**I've tried** using middlewares, but some of its usages are now deprecated and had no success. Whats the correct way to solving this problem?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
await Marcacao.updateMany({team: req.params._id}, {team: null});
```

This was the solution. Where req.params._id is the team ID.